# How to Place Image above Iframe

Tags: css

I want to add an image on top of an iframe that I imported from the server, but I can't find the correct css code to do ?

i want to display an image within an iframe on my webpage. However, the problem is that I can't get it to expand to 100% of its size.

What I want to do is the following.

1. Have an iframe on my webpage.
2. Make the image expand to full-size and as a reaction, the iframe allows me to scroll.

Currently, here's the code I have:

```
<body>
  <div id="GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa" style="
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  ">
    <iframe style="
      display: inherit;
      z-index: 10001;
      position: absolute;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
      top: 400px;
      left: 500%;
      margin-left: 200px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    " src="http://localhost:3000/d/ccbd5cd2-d8c7-482c-809e-157191a029db/new-dashboard?orgId=1&from=1685031277500&to=1685032916500&viewPanel=1" id="iframe-overlay" title="iframe">
  </iframe>

    <img style="
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      opacity: 1;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      top: 23% !important;
      left: 48% !important;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
      z-index: 99999999;
      margin-left: 192px;" id="close-overlay" " src="image.png" />
</div>
<style>
body {
  width: 100px  ;
}
#GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa {
    --iframeW: 1080px; /*the defaults set by browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe*/
    --iframeH: 1500px;
    }
#GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa iframe {
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    top: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: calc(50% - (var(--iframeW) / 2));
    position: absolute;
}

#GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: calc(50% + (var(--iframeW) / 2));
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
</style>
<script>
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
const img = document.querySelector('img');
  iframe.style = '';
  img.style = '';
</script>
</body>
```

and the output Like This :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stLgn.png)

i want Output like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xpEa.png)

....................................................................................................
can you help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just refactor your code with the help of @A-haworth

With this approch, both of the image and the iframe are set without the need of a z-index. So this will result as the thing you are looking for :)

#### So your code should look like this

### HTML

```
<div id="GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa">
    <iframe src="http://localhost:3000/d/ccbd5cd2-d8c7-482c-809e-157191a029db/new-dashboard?orgId=1&from=1685031277500&to=1685032916500&viewPanel=1" id="iframe-overlay" title="iframe">
  </iframe>

    <img id="close-overlay" src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/48/42/64/360_F_248426448_NVKLywWqArG2ADUxDq6QprtIzsF82dMF.jpg" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  width: 100px  ;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa iframe {
  top: 40px;
  left: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

#GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Codepen for further details : https://codepen.io/ColinMsd/pen/gOQooqb?editors=1100

Comment: Why can't it be fixed? And what is the significance of giving the img a z-index (seeing as it's painted after the iframe and lies in the same place).

Comment: It can't be fixed cause with fixed position your child divs won't apply z-index. If you need absolutely a fixed position add another container inside with position relative

Comment: Z-index just tell to the image to go above the iframe

Comment: child divs will apply z-index within a fixed parent. And the z-index on the img is redundant because it occupies the same position as the iframe and is painted after it.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand the question then, but, for me, the author wanted to set an image above his iframe. With both element set as absolute use of Z-index is mandatory. And his direct parent should be relative not fixed as he set it.  

Do you have any better/cleaner solution ?

Comment: As the img element is also absolute and has the same top and left, at least in your code, it will go on top of the iframe without needing a z-index.

Comment: Yes ! Didn't saw that ! Code is cleaner now

Comment: You still have this 'To play with Z-index your main container should always bet set as Position: relative' which is not correct.

Comment: Yes did a quick edit before going to lunch should be right now